# C/C++ ftplib: Undefined reference to _imp__FtpInit

Tags: c++, c, ftp, ftplib

I am trying to use a C/C++ FTP library ([>here's the website](http://www.nbpfaus.net/~pfau/ftplib/)). When I try to call the FtpInit() function I get a compilation error telling me that there is an `undefined reference to _imp__FtpInit`. This is what I'm trying to compile:

```
#include "ftplib/ftplib.h"

int main()
{
    FtpInit();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to set your `-L` library path to the location where you installed the library, and use `-lftplib` (or similar depending on the actual library file's name) to link the library?

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio, add the .lib file to the "Additional Dependencies" setting in project properties/Linker/Input.

You may also need to set "Additional Library Directories" in Project Properties/Linker/General